# Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'm using Maven. I'm having trouble downloading a dependency and getting the error, "Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.10.final".
I delete whole project an clone it again from git.I update maven dependencies, still there is no hibernate file load in it.
Here is my pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>gau</groupId>
<artifactId>shoppingbackend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>shoppingbackend</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- H2 Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database connection pooling -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- update to latest java version -->
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Git link of my project

https://github.com/Gauravmokashi/online-shopping.git

Comment: Seems like `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` dependency references old Hibernate 4.x

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no changes even after deleting  hibernate-jpa-2.0-api and updating maven

Comment: Ok, can you check if there's a jar for hibernate-core 5.2.10.Final in your maven repositories folder? Maybe there's a corrupt jar there.

Comment: There is no jar for  hibernate-core 5.2.10.Final , even after updating maven, it is unable to download this particular jar.

Answer (score 1):

You may check if any other *Maven* projects of yours are currently using this dependency for `Hibernate`.

If they do, then deactivate them and after, put this dependency into the project's `pom.xml` file and update **ALL** your *Maven* projects.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue and I tried many things like restarting *Eclipse* and `maven clean`

If you are using *Eclipse* just `right-click -> project -> select run-as -> click maven install`.